# Change PHP variable syntax from object to array in Notepad++ with search/replace

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I need to replace one-dimensional object property accessing syntax to array element accessing syntax

Examples:

- `$variable -> child`
- `$variable->child`

both should be converted to:

```
$variable['child']
```

Answer (score 0):

Find what:

```
\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*) *-> *([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)
```

Replace with

```
$\1['\2']
```

Make the search mode as "regular expression" of course.  Here, a regex representing [PHP variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) is `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`.

Comment: Thank you very much.. :)
I already figure out like this.. but it was not working with spaces.. :)
`(\$+)(\w+)(->)(\w+)` replacing with `$1$2['$4']`

Comment: How about `(\$+)(\w+) *(->) *(\w+)` replacing with `$1$2['$4']`?  `*` means the previous character/phrase repeated by 0 to multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Find: `(\$\w+) *-> *(\w+)`

Replace: `$1['$2']`

- `(\$\w+)` capture a literal dollar sign then one or more [a-zA-Z0-9_] characters
- `*-> *`  match zero or more spaces, then hyphen, then greater than, then zero or more spaces
- `(\w+)`   capture one or more [a-zA-Z0-9_] characters

Then use `$1` and `$2` to generate the desired dynamic replacement with array syntax.

As commented under the other answer, it doesn't make sense to look for one or more literal dollar signs (`\$+`) because there should only be one -- I hope you aren't using "variable variables" (`$$variable`), but it wouldn't matter in this context if you did.